# Rails Rspec test that a controller has triggered Websockets event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, websocket

In my controller I have the following code that triggers a websockets event inside the update method:

```
WebsocketRails[recipient.id].trigger "new_activity", "Shared" if recipient.online?
```

How can I test that my controller is triggering this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expect(triggerable = double).to receive(:trigger)
  .with('new_activity', 'Shared')
allow(WebsocketRails).to receive(:[]).and_return(triggerable)
get :myroute
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I would ever had got to that point on my own. It does't pass unfortunately and I think it is because I have not subscribed to the private channel. I have tried to subscribe by doing `create_event('websocket_rails.subscribe_private', @michael.id).dispatch` but it doesn't trigger the controller event that is mapped in the events.rb file. Any ideas?

Comment: Cancel that, I think it may have been my `if recipient.online?` clause. I'll do some more digging

Comment: Yes it was the `if recipient.online?` statement. I made the recipient appear online and now it works great. Thanks so much!